# .tif image exported from QGIS will not load in ARCGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, geotiff-tiff

I have saved a layer in QGIS as a .tif image, and when I try to add this to an ARCGIS MXD I am using for a project it does not appear.

When I add it to a blank MXD the image loads, however, if I try to zoom in then the image fills the entire screeen and the map scale jumps to 1:500,000,000.

If the MXD already has other images in then the .tif image just does not appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a coordinate system issue. Make sure the coordinate system of both images (or other layers) in you data frame is defined. You can define a coordinate system

- via the Catalog > Double-click the dataset > Coordinate System tab > Choose a coordinate system.
- using the [Define Projection](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/define-projection.htm) tool.
  Make sure you choose the right coordinate system of course.

And define a datum transformation in ArcMap if necessary (i.e. if coordinate systems are based on different datums), so that your data is properly aligned.